# Issues to user PostgreSQL -

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sqlite, pg

Whatever that I try to do is generating the error message below:

/home/diogodalla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)

I'm using PG on my gemFile, I don't know why it keep looking for sqlite3.

My Gem File:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.6.2'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.4'
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'chartkick'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Also my DataBase.yml:

```html
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.1 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: TaskManager

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: TaskManager_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: TaskManager_production
  username: TaskManager
  password: <%= ENV['TASKMANAGER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

And my dependecies.rb

```html
require "set"
require "thread"
require "concurrent/map"
require "pathname"
require "active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing"
require "active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors"
require "active_support/core_ext/module/introspection"
require "active_support/core_ext/module/anonymous"
require "active_support/core_ext/object/blank"
require "active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting"
require "active_support/core_ext/load_error"
require "active_support/core_ext/name_error"
require "active_support/core_ext/string/starts_ends_with"
require "active_support/dependencies/interlock"
require "active_support/inflector"

module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
  module Dependencies #:nodoc:
    extend self

    mattr_accessor :interlock
    self.interlock = Interlock.new

    # :doc:

    # Execute the supplied block without interference from any
    # concurrent loads.
    def self.run_interlock
      Dependencies.interlock.running { yield }
    end

    # Execute the supplied block while holding an exclusive lock,
    # preventing any other thread from being inside a #run_interlock
    # block at the same time.
    def self.load_interlock
      Dependencies.interlock.loading { yield }
    end

    # Execute the supplied block while holding an exclusive lock,
    # preventing any other thread from being inside a #run_interlock
    # block at the same time.
    def self.unload_interlock
      Dependencies.interlock.unloading { yield }
    end

    # :nodoc:

    # Should we turn on Ruby warnings on the first load of dependent files?
    mattr_accessor :warnings_on_first_load
    self.warnings_on_first_load = false

    # All files ever loaded.
    mattr_accessor :history
    self.history = Set.new

    # All files currently loaded.
    mattr_accessor :loaded
    self.loaded = Set.new

    # Stack of files being loaded.
    mattr_accessor :loading
    self.loading = []

    # Should we load files or require them?
    mattr_accessor :mechanism
    self.mechanism = ENV["NO_RELOAD"] ? :require : :load

    # The set of directories from which we may automatically load files. Files
    # under these directories will be reloaded on each request in development mode,
    # unless the directory also appears in autoload_once_paths.
    mattr_accessor :autoload_paths
    self.autoload_paths = []

    # The set of directories from which automatically loaded constants are loaded
    # only once. All directories in this set must also be present in +autoload_paths+.
    mattr_accessor :autoload_once_paths
    self.autoload_once_paths = []

    # An array of qualified constant names that have been loaded. Adding a name
    # to this array will cause it to be unloaded the next time Dependencies are
    # cleared.
    mattr_accessor :autoloaded_constants
    self.autoloaded_constants = []

    # An array of constant names that need to be unloaded on every request. Used
    # to allow arbitrary constants to be marked for unloading.
    mattr_accessor :explicitly_unloadable_constants
    self.explicitly_unloadable_constants = []

    # The WatchStack keeps a stack of the modules being watched as files are
    # loaded. If a file in the process of being loaded (parent.rb) triggers the
    # load of another file (child.rb) the stack will ensure that child.rb
    # handles the new constants.
    #
    # If child.rb is being autoloaded, its constants will be added to
    # autoloaded_constants. If it was being `require`d, they will be discarded.
    #
    # This is handled by walking back up the watch stack and adding the constants
    # found by child.rb to the list of original constants in parent.rb.
    class WatchStack
      include Enumerable

      # @watching is a stack of lists of constants being watched. For instance,
      # if parent.rb is autoloaded, the stack will look like [[Object]]. If
      # parent.rb then requires namespace/child.rb, the stack will look like
      # [[Object], [Namespace]].

      def initialize
        @watching = []
        @stack = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
      end

      def each(&block)
        @stack.each(&block)
      end

      def watching?
        !@watching.empty?
      end

      # Returns a list of new constants found since the last call to
      # <tt>watch_namespaces</tt>.
      def new_constants
        constants = []

        # Grab the list of namespaces that we're looking for new constants under
        @watching.last.each do |namespace|
          # Retrieve the constants that were present under the namespace when watch_namespaces
          # was originally called
          original_constants = @stack[namespace].last

          mod = Inflector.constantize(namespace) if Dependencies.qualified_const_defined?(namespace)
          next unless mod.is_a?(Module)

          new_constants = mod.constants(false) - original_constants

        
          @stack[namespace].each do |namespace_constants|
            namespace_constants.concat(new_constants)
          end

          # Normalize the list of new constants, and add them to the list we will return
          new_constants.each do |suffix|
            constants << ([namespace, suffix] - ["Object"]).join("::".freeze)
          end
        end
        constants
      ensure
        # A call to new_constants is always called after a call to watch_namespaces
        pop_modules(@watching.pop)
      end

    
      def watch_namespaces(namespaces)
        @watching << namespaces.map do |namespace|
          module_name = Dependencies.to_constant_name(namespace)
          original_constants = Dependencies.qualified_const_defined?(module_name) ?
            Inflector.constantize(module_name).constants(false) : []

          @stack[module_name] << original_constants
          module_name
        end
      end

      private
        def pop_modules(modules)
          modules.each { |mod| @stack[mod].pop }
        end
    end

    # An internal stack used to record which constants are loaded by any block.
    mattr_accessor :constant_watch_stack
    self.constant_watch_stack = WatchStack.new

    # Module includes this module.
    module ModuleConstMissing #:nodoc:
      def self.append_features(base)
        base.class_eval do
          # Emulate #exclude via an ivar
          return if defined?(@_const_missing) && @_const_missing
          @_const_missing = instance_method(:const_missing)
          remove_method(:const_missing)
        end
        super
      end

      def self.exclude_from(base)
        base.class_eval do
          define_method :const_missing, @_const_missing
          @_const_missing = nil
        end
      end

      def const_missing(const_name)
        from_mod = anonymous? ? guess_for_anonymous(const_name) : self
        Dependencies.load_missing_constant(from_mod, const_name)
      end

    
      def guess_for_anonymous(const_name)
        if Object.const_defined?(const_name)
          raise NameError.new "#{const_name} cannot be autoloaded from an anonymous class or module", const_name
        else
          Object
        end
      end

      def unloadable(const_desc = self)
        super(const_desc)
      end
    end

    # Object includes this module.
    module Loadable #:nodoc:
      def self.exclude_from(base)
        base.class_eval do
          define_method(:load, Kernel.instance_method(:load))
          private :load
        end
      end

      def require_or_load(file_name)
        Dependencies.require_or_load(file_name)
      end

 
      def require_dependency(file_name, message = "No such file to load -- %s.rb")
        file_name = file_name.to_path if file_name.respond_to?(:to_path)
        unless file_name.is_a?(String)
          raise ArgumentError, "the file name must either be a String or implement #to_path -- you passed #{file_name.inspect}"
        end

        Dependencies.depend_on(file_name, message)
      end

      def load_dependency(file)
        if Dependencies.load? && Dependencies.constant_watch_stack.watching?
          Dependencies.new_constants_in(Object) { yield }
        else
          yield
        end
      rescue Exception => exception  # errors from loading file
        exception.blame_file! file if exception.respond_to? :blame_file!
        raise
      end

      def unloadable(const_desc)
        Dependencies.mark_for_unload const_desc
      end

      private

        def load(file, wrap = false)
          result = false
          load_dependency(file) { result = super }
          result
        end

        def require(file)
          result = false
          load_dependency(file) { result = super }
          result
        end
    end

    # Exception file-blaming.
    module Blamable #:nodoc:
      def blame_file!(file)
        (@blamed_files ||= []).unshift file
      end

      def blamed_files
        @blamed_files ||= []
      end

      def describe_blame
        return nil if blamed_files.empty?
        "This error occurred while loading the following files:\n   #{blamed_files.join "\n   "}"
      end

      def copy_blame!(exc)
        @blamed_files = exc.blamed_files.clone
        self
      end
    end

    def hook!
      Object.class_eval { include Loadable }
      Module.class_eval { include ModuleConstMissing }
      Exception.class_eval { include Blamable }
    end

    def unhook!
      ModuleConstMissing.exclude_from(Module)
      Loadable.exclude_from(Object)
    end

    def load?
      mechanism == :load
    end

    def depend_on(file_name, message = "No such file to load -- %s.rb")
      path = search_for_file(file_name)
      require_or_load(path || file_name)
    rescue LoadError => load_error
      if file_name = load_error.message[/ -- (.*?)(\.rb)?$/, 1]
        load_error.message.replace(message % file_name)
        load_error.copy_blame!(load_error)
      end
      raise
    end

    def clear
      Dependencies.unload_interlock do
        loaded.clear
        loading.clear
        remove_unloadable_constants!
      end
    end

    def require_or_load(file_name, const_path = nil)
      file_name = $` if file_name =~ /\.rb\z/
      expanded = File.expand_path(file_name)
      return if loaded.include?(expanded)

      Dependencies.load_interlock do
        # Maybe it got loaded while we were waiting for our lock:
        return if loaded.include?(expanded)

        loaded << expanded
        loading << expanded

        begin
          if load?
            # Enable warnings if this file has not been loaded before and
            # warnings_on_first_load is set.
            load_args = ["#{file_name}.rb"]
            load_args << const_path unless const_path.nil?

            if !warnings_on_first_load || history.include?(expanded)
              result = load_file(*load_args)
            else
              enable_warnings { result = load_file(*load_args) }
            end
          else
            result = require file_name
          end
        rescue Exception
          loaded.delete expanded
          raise
        ensure
          loading.pop
        end

        # Record history *after* loading so first load gets warnings.
        history << expanded
        result
      end
    end

    # Is the provided constant path defined?
    def qualified_const_defined?(path)
      Object.const_defined?(path, false)
    end

  
    def loadable_constants_for_path(path, bases = autoload_paths)
      path = $` if path =~ /\.rb\z/
      expanded_path = File.expand_path(path)
      paths = []

      bases.each do |root|
        expanded_root = File.expand_path(root)
        next unless expanded_path.start_with?(expanded_root)

        root_size = expanded_root.size
        next if expanded_path[root_size] != ?/.freeze

        nesting = expanded_path[(root_size + 1)..-1]
        paths << nesting.camelize unless nesting.blank?
      end

      paths.uniq!
      paths
    end

    # Search for a file in autoload_paths matching the provided suffix.
    def search_for_file(path_suffix)
      path_suffix = path_suffix.sub(/(\.rb)?$/, ".rb".freeze)

      autoload_paths.each do |root|
        path = File.join(root, path_suffix)
        return path if File.file? path
      end
      nil # Gee, I sure wish we had first_match ;-)
    end

 
    def autoloadable_module?(path_suffix)
      autoload_paths.each do |load_path|
        return load_path if File.directory? File.join(load_path, path_suffix)
      end
      nil
    end

    def load_once_path?(path)
      # to_s works around a ruby issue where String#starts_with?(Pathname)
      # will raise a TypeError: no implicit conversion of Pathname into String
      autoload_once_paths.any? { |base| path.starts_with? base.to_s }
    end

 
    def autoload_module!(into, const_name, qualified_name, path_suffix)
      return nil unless base_path = autoloadable_module?(path_suffix)
      mod = Module.new
      into.const_set const_name, mod
      autoloaded_constants << qualified_name unless autoload_once_paths.include?(base_path)
      mod
    end

  
    def load_file(path, const_paths = loadable_constants_for_path(path))
      const_paths = [const_paths].compact unless const_paths.is_a? Array
      parent_paths = const_paths.collect { |const_path| const_path[/.*(?=::)/] || ::Object }

      result = nil
      newly_defined_paths = new_constants_in(*parent_paths) do
        result = Kernel.load path
      end

      autoloaded_constants.concat newly_defined_paths unless load_once_path?(path)
      autoloaded_constants.uniq!
      result
    end

    def qualified_name_for(mod, name)
      mod_name = to_constant_name mod
      mod_name == "Object" ? name.to_s : "#{mod_name}::#{name}"
    end

   
    def load_missing_constant(from_mod, const_name)
      unless qualified_const_defined?(from_mod.name) && Inflector.constantize(from_mod.name).equal?(from_mod)
        raise ArgumentError, "A copy of #{from_mod} has been removed from the module tree but is still active!"
      end

      qualified_name = qualified_name_for from_mod, const_name
      path_suffix = qualified_name.underscore

      file_path = search_for_file(path_suffix)

      if file_path
        expanded = File.expand_path(file_path)
        expanded.sub!(/\.rb\z/, "".freeze)

        if loading.include?(expanded)
          raise "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant #{qualified_name}"
        else
          require_or_load(expanded, qualified_name)
          raise LoadError, "Unable to autoload constant #{qualified_name}, expected #{file_path} to define it" unless from_mod.const_defined?(const_name, false)
          return from_mod.const_get(const_name)
        end
      elsif mod = autoload_module!(from_mod, const_name, qualified_name, path_suffix)
        return mod
      elsif (parent = from_mod.parent) && parent != from_mod &&
            ! from_mod.parents.any? { |p| p.const_defined?(const_name, false) }
      

          return parent.const_missing(const_name)
        rescue NameError => e
          raise unless e.missing_name? qualified_name_for(parent, const_name)
        end
      end

      name_error = NameError.new("uninitialized constant #{qualified_name}", const_name)
      name_error.set_backtrace(caller.reject { |l| l.starts_with? __FILE__ })
      raise name_error
    end

    # Remove the constants that have been autoloaded, and those that have been
    # marked for unloading. Before each constant is removed a callback is sent
    # to its class/module if it implements +before_remove_const+.
    #
    # The callback implementation should be restricted to cleaning up caches, etc.
    # as the environment will be in an inconsistent state, e.g. other constants
    # may have already been unloaded and not accessible.
    def remove_unloadable_constants!
      autoloaded_constants.each { |const| remove_constant const }
      autoloaded_constants.clear
      Reference.clear!
      explicitly_unloadable_constants.each { |const| remove_constant const }
    end

    class ClassCache
      def initialize
        @store = Concurrent::Map.new
      end

      def empty?
        @store.empty?
      end

      def key?(key)
        @store.key?(key)
      end

      def get(key)
        key = key.name if key.respond_to?(:name)
        @store[key] ||= Inflector.constantize(key)
      end
      alias :[] :get

      def safe_get(key)
        key = key.name if key.respond_to?(:name)
        @store[key] ||= Inflector.safe_constantize(key)
      end

      def store(klass)
        return self unless klass.respond_to?(:name)
        raise(ArgumentError, "anonymous classes cannot be cached") if klass.name.empty?
        @store[klass.name] = klass
        self
      end

      def clear!
        @store.clear
      end
    end

    Reference = ClassCache.new

    # Store a reference to a class +klass+.
    def reference(klass)
      Reference.store klass
    end

    # Get the reference for class named +name+.
    # Raises an exception if referenced class does not exist.
    def constantize(name)
      Reference.get(name)
    end

    # Get the reference for class named +name+ if one exists.
    # Otherwise returns +nil+.
    def safe_constantize(name)
      Reference.safe_get(name)
    end

    # Determine if the given constant has been automatically loaded.
    def autoloaded?(desc)
      return false if desc.is_a?(Module) && desc.anonymous?
      name = to_constant_name desc
      return false unless qualified_const_defined?(name)
      return autoloaded_constants.include?(name)
    end

    # Will the provided constant descriptor be unloaded?
    def will_unload?(const_desc)
      autoloaded?(const_desc) ||
        explicitly_unloadable_constants.include?(to_constant_name(const_desc))
    end

    # Mark the provided constant name for unloading. This constant will be
    # unloaded on each request, not just the next one.
    def mark_for_unload(const_desc)
      name = to_constant_name const_desc
      if explicitly_unloadable_constants.include? name
        false
      else
        explicitly_unloadable_constants << name
        true
      end
    end

    # Run the provided block and detect the new constants that were loaded during
    # its execution. Constants may only be regarded as 'new' once -- so if the
    # block calls +new_constants_in+ again, then the constants defined within the
    # inner call will not be reported in this one.
    #
    # If the provided block does not run to completion, and instead raises an
    # exception, any new constants are regarded as being only partially defined
    # and will be removed immediately.
    def new_constants_in(*descs)
      constant_watch_stack.watch_namespaces(descs)
      success = false

      begin
        yield # Now yield to the code that is to define new constants.
        success = true
      ensure
        new_constants = constant_watch_stack.new_constants

        return new_constants if success

        # Remove partially loaded constants.
        new_constants.each { |c| remove_constant(c) }
      end
    end

    # Convert the provided const desc to a qualified constant name (as a string).
    # A module, class, symbol, or string may be provided.
    def to_constant_name(desc) #:nodoc:
      case desc
      when String then desc.sub(/^::/, "")
      when Symbol then desc.to_s
      when Module
        desc.name ||
          raise(ArgumentError, "Anonymous modules have no name to be referenced by")
        else raise TypeError, "Not a valid constant descriptor: #{desc.inspect}"
      end
    end

    def remove_constant(const) #:nodoc:
      # Normalize ::Foo, ::Object::Foo, Object::Foo, Object::Object::Foo, etc. as Foo.
      normalized = const.to_s.sub(/\A::/, "")
      normalized.sub!(/\A(Object::)+/, "")

      constants = normalized.split("::")
      to_remove = constants.pop

      # Remove the file path from the loaded list.
      file_path = search_for_file(const.underscore)
      if file_path
        expanded = File.expand_path(file_path)
        expanded.sub!(/\.rb\z/, "")
        loaded.delete(expanded)
      end

      if constants.empty?
        parent = Object
      else

        parent_name = constants.join("::")
        return unless qualified_const_defined?(parent_name)
        parent = constantize(parent_name)
      end

      # In an autoloaded user.rb like this
      #
      #   autoload :Foo, 'foo'
      #
      #   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      #   end
      #
      # we correctly register "Foo" as being autoloaded. But if the app does
      # not use the "Foo" constant we need to be careful not to trigger
      # loading "foo.rb" ourselves. While #const_defined? and #const_get? do
      # require the file, #autoload? and #remove_const don't.
      #
      # We are going to remove the constant nonetheless ---which exists as
      # far as Ruby is concerned--- because if the user removes the macro
      # call from a class or module that were not autoloaded, as in the
      # example above with Object, accessing to that constant must err.
      unless parent.autoload?(to_remove)
        begin
          constantized = parent.const_get(to_remove, false)
        rescue NameError
          # The constant is no longer reachable, just skip it.
          return
        else
          constantized.before_remove_const if constantized.respond_to?(:before_remove_const)
        end
      end

      begin
        parent.instance_eval { remove_const to_remove }
      rescue NameError
        # The constant is no longer reachable, just skip it.
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveSupport::Dependencies.hook!
```

Any tips abut it?

thank you all.

Comment: Please try to cut down the size of the source code you've posted. Just show the essentials. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Can you delete your Gemfile.lock, then try bundle install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you install libraries ? Try following procedure before running Rails, please.

Remove local libraries and re-install

```
$ rm -rf ./vendor/bundle
$ bundle install --path ./vendor/bundle
$ bundle exec rails server
```